# Flutter tab losing focus or not responding to tap

Tags: flutter, navigationbar

I have a `flutter` app where the main screen is a `tabBar` like this:

```
class MainRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([SystemUiOverlay.top]);
    return MaterialApp(
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 3,
        child: Scaffold(
          body: TabBarView(
            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            children: [
              Container(
                color: Color.fromRGBO(40, 40, 40, 1.0),
                child: Tab1(),
              ),
              Container(
                color: Color.fromRGBO(40, 40, 40, 1.0),
                child: Tab2(),
              ),
              Container(
                color: Color.fromRGBO(40, 40, 40, 1.0),
                child: Tab3(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          bottomNavigationBar: TabBar(
            labelStyle: null,
            tabs: [
              Tab(
                icon: Icon(MdiIcons.home),
              ),
              Tab(
                icon: Icon(MdiIcons.settings),
              ),
              Tab(
                icon: Icon(MdiIcons.account),
              )
            ],
            indicatorColor: Colors.transparent,
            labelColor: Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 1),
            unselectedLabelColor: Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, .3),

          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        ),
      ),
    );
```

And for example, my Tab3() looks like that:

```
class Tab3 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => Tab3State();
}

class Tab3State extends State<Tab3> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: Implement build
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
          width: MediaQuery
              .of(context)
              .size
              .width,
          height: MediaQuery
              .of(context)
              .size
              .height,
          color: Colors.white,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                child: RaisedButton(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                  textColor: Colors.white,
                  onPressed: () {
                    print("GAllery tapped");
                  },
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  elevation: 10,
                  child: Text("Gallery"),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The app runs ok in the emulator but when i run in on a real Adnroid device it has an issue with the tap.

When the `MainRoute` is showed, if i try to navigate to the last tab by tapping the icon, the first time i tap it is not recognized (out of focus???) the second time and from now on it works as expected, same with all tabs only on the first tap.

Now, when the `Tab3` is loaded, the Gallery button does not recognize the first tap (out of focus too???) but then the second tap is recognized and it works from now on.

Is it a problem with the code? a problem with the architecture of the code? a problem with my real device (Samsung Galaxy S7)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's related, but you shouldn't have 2 `Scaffold` widgets.
Try removing the one in the `Tab3State` class, you have no need for it there anyway.

Comment: nope, it did not help removing the Scaffold, but thanks!

Comment: I pasted your code (minus the extra scaffold) and ran it on a motorola g5 plus, seems to work fine. I would try with something silly (maybe just a container) instead of your Tab3() to try to narrow down where the problem is coming from..

Comment: really?, bottombar taps and raisedbutton tap on tab3 works at the first tap after launch?, that is very good info to know...maybe its something with my device....

Comment: It might be something with your other tabs as well. Try replacing them with simple containers. i.e. instead of: `Container(
                color: Color.fromRGBO(40, 40, 40, 1.0),
                child: Tab1(),
              ),`, use a child of: `Container(color: Colors.white, child: Center(child: Text('tab1'),)` or something